# Always explicitly calling the constructor of parent class in Python

Tags: python, oop

Looking for best practices here:

Is it always better to explicitly call the parent constructor within a child class irrespective whether it is defined or not?

Example:

```
# no explicit constructor
class Parent(object):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
  # call parent constructor
   def __init__(self):
      super(Child, self). ___init__()
```

Comment: Yes. See [Python's super() considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for some reasons as to why.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks for the pointer/s